# Counting problem: Find the probability that exactly 3 shoes are filled with chocolate mice (and so the other 3 shoes remain empty).

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am struggling with the following question on counting problems:

A rather tipsy Saint Nicholas has 6 chocolate mice. At the chimney there are 6
children's shoes. Because of his tipsy condition Saint Nicholas stops chocolate mice in
the shoes of the children, but posting each new chocolate mouse in a shoe is
independent of the placements of the preceding chocolate mice. So, it is possible that
one shoe is filled with more chocolate mice and another shoe remains empty.

a) Find the probability that at least one shoe remains empty.
b) Find the probability that exactly 3 shoes are filled with chocolate mice (and so the
other 3 shoes remain empty).

My reasoning was that if you want exactly 3 shoes to be filled with chocolate mice, you can divide them in 3 ways: (4 1 1) (3 2 1) (2 2 2)

I called the chocolate mice as letters, so AAAA B C means putting 4 mice in shoe 1 , 1 mice in shoe2 and 1 mice in shoe 3

AAAA B C (here you have $\binom{6}{4}$ for shoe A) $\cdot$ ($\binom{2}{1}$ for shoe B) $\cdot$ ($\binom{1}{1}$) for shoe C)

AAA BB C ($\binom{6}{3}$) $\cdot$ ($\binom{3}{2}$) $\cdot$ ($\binom{1}{1}$)

AA BB CC ($\binom{6}{2}$) $\cdot$ ($\binom{4}{2}$) $\cdot$ ($\binom{2}{2}$)

And the total ways of dividing 6 mice over 6 shoes is $6^6$.

So I would say that this probability is

$$\frac{\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{3}3!}{6^6} + \frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{6}{3}3!}{6^6} + \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{3}3!}{6^6}$$

where the $\binom{6}{3}$ terms come from selecting which three of the six shoes will receive at least one chocolate mouse.

However this is wrong and I do not understand why, and I don’t understand their solution. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMfn2.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the remaining terms accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem in your reasoning is that you think that the letters represent mice while they actually represent shoes. If I call $u, v, w$ the three numbers that you are adding to get the result, the true answer is not $u+v+w$ but $u/2 + v + w/6$. I'll try to explain why.

Suppose the letters represent shoes and that the shoes are lined up from left to right. In order to put 4 mice in 1 shoe and 1 mouse in 2 other shoes, Saint Nicholas must choose 3 shoes to realize one configuration among
\begin{equation}
AAAA\ B\ C,\quad A\ BBBB\ C,\quad A\ B\ CCCC
\end{equation}
There are 6 ways to choose the shoe that will get 4 mice and once this is done, there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to choose the other shoes. So there are 60 ways to choose the shoes instead of $\binom{6}{3}3! = 120$ that you found.

In the third case $AA\ BB\ CC$, there are just $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose the shoes instead of the $\binom{6}{3}3!$ that you found.

In the second configuration, there are 6 ways to choose the shoe that will receive 3 mice, then 5 ways to choose the shoe that will receive 2 mice, then 4 ways to choose the shoe that receives 1 mouse. So $6\times 5\times 4$. By chance, this is equal to $\binom{6}{3}3!$

**A more theoretical way:**
The distribution of the mice is a random map $f$ from the set $M$ of the 6 mice into the set $S$ of the 6 shoes. There are $6^6$ such maps. There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose a subset $X\subset S$ with cardinality 3 and the number of [surjections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) from $M$ to $X$ is $3!\left\{6\atop 3\right\}$,
where $\left\{6\atop 3\right\}=90$ is a [Stirling number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) of the second kind, hence the probability
\begin{equation}
p = \binom{6}{3}3!\frac{90}{6^6} = 0.23148148
\end{equation}

Comment: I just needed 1 more minute! I'll post my answer anyway....

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember when you had to find the number of words from the letters of something like $HELLO$, or $BOOKKEEPER$? Dividing by factorials was a key step in these problems. Here, everything you've done is right, except for two things:

1. In the case $AAAA$ $B$ $C$, you choose the three shoes, then you distribute the mice among them, and then you permute. However, there is a catch. Suppose after choosing three shoes named $P$, $Q$ and $R$, and by multiplying by $3!$, you've permuted the mice, but you are overcounting (you're counting every case twice, for example, if $PQR$ have $4$, $1$ and $1$ mice respectively, and you exchange the mice in $Q$ and $R$, then it is not a new case) So divide the probability of this case by $2! = 2$.
2. The same logic applies in $AA$ $BB$ $CC$, if all $P$, $Q$, and $R$ have 2 mice, and you permute the same mice among these $3$, it does not make a difference. So divide the probability of this case by $3!$.

Now simplify to get the expression in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense !